# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available why configuring database for Oracle Database 18c XE on Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle18c

I completed Oracle PreInstall 18c and Oracle 18c Database installation successfully.

When I run /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure command I come across with the following error.

```
 BEGIN 
dbms_backup_restore.resetCfileSection(dbms_backup_restore.RTYP_DFILE_COPY); 
END;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
```

By the way, another Oracle 11XE is installed in the computer. Do you think I have to kill all the ports of 11XE and configure it again or the problem comes from any other place?

You can find other error logs below.
Thank you for your helps.

```
 oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepExecutionException: ORA-01034: 
 ORACLE not available at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.RmanRestoreDatafilesStep.executeImpl(RmanRestoreDatafilesStep.java:205) at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:308) at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.callStep(BasicStep.java:360) at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.CloneRmanRestoreStep.executeImpl(CloneRmanRestoreStep.java:391)
```

Comment: Are you able to sign into the database? Do you see any other errors in the alert log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-01034: ORACLE not available , means installation is not successful. please verify the database instances are running by using 'ps -ef | grep pmon'.